# Exponential (base nagative) limit involving the point at infinity

Tags: limits

When i tried to solve

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } (-1/2)^ x$

i am little confused  ,since  x is real  $(-1/2)^ x$may be undefined for some powers. can we  say ,since $ \  \left |  \frac{-1}{2} \right |<1$ the answer is 0 (as we do in geometric series)?

i tried to draw  the function in geogebra  $(-1/2)^ x$ but it showed blank page but wolfram  calculated the limit as 0.

Thanks

Comment: What is the domain ?

Comment: The function is not defined as $x\to\infty$ (mainly for irrational values of $x$ and rational $x$ with even denominator) so it does not make sense to consider the limit of this function. Assumption is that we are using real valued functions of a real variable. On the other if $n$ is positive integer variable then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1/2)^{n}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Domain of function is R and the function 2^x goes to infinity as x approaches infinity and so it's inverse I. E. 1/(2^x)  approaches 0 and so function value is 0 as x approaches infinity. Even though the function is  negative function value approaches 0 as x approaches infinity.

Comment: Is my approach correct?

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, but the second sentence is incorrect. The given function is not exactly negative but rather tries to use a negative number as base and that restricts the exponent as well. So for current question the exponent $x$ makes sense only when $x$ is rational with odd denominator. And the domain is thus not whole of $\mathbb{R} $.

Comment: Yes you are right I was wrong domain is R-1/2n where n is integer but the answer remains same because as x tends to  infinity function value reaches zero.